# JavaScript File For Each HTML File?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, haml

I have a javascript file that handles the scripting of several HTML files.

I started running into issues as everything is just written out, and nothing is called in functions (so all AJAX calls for instance are called at all pages, even though each call should only be called at one page one).

What is the best way to go about improving/fixing this? Here are the two ways that I thought of doing it:

1. Create a separate JS file for each HTML file
2. Put all JS code in functions and call each function respectively

I am leaning towards putting all my code in functions. However, when I did:

```
<script src="the_source">
  call_function
</script>
```

That didn't seem to work. I put that right before where the responsible HTML was. I originally wrote it in Haml as follows:

```
%script{:src => "src"}
  call_function
```

How can I get this HTML function calling working?

Or is separating them whereby each HTML file has a different JS file considered a better solution? The problem is that there is a lot of shared code between them. To solve this, I can create a different file with the shared code in objects which can be called from the other JS files as needed.

What is the cleaner approach/solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put your JS code into several different files, one for each page. 
This can help your site run quicker (admittedly not by much) because the browser isn't running through tons and tons of code to find the required function. 
Also, (and this is just a personal opinion) , a JS file with just a long list of short functions is quite ugly and seems less efficient.

And yeah, include an extra file with the shared code on. Try to make sure nothing is repeated unnecessarily in the files! 
Good luck! :)

Comment: If I do this, how can I include the shared file in other JS files? Just add it into the HTML <script> before the other files are added?

Comment: yeah, just link the shared code file to **all** the HTML pages with `<script type="text/javascript" src="shared.js"></script>` and then link **only** the relevant JS files to each page. :)

Answer (score 1):

To call function use:

```
call_function();
```

Edited:

```
<script src="the_source"></script>
<script >
  call_function();
</script>
```

where "`the_source`" is path to your js file

End edit

To separate the logic in every page i would just create some settings object and put there flag for cases you want to have separate:

```
//this code should be on every page you need your javascript file
<script src="the_source"></script>
<script>
  var settings = {
        mode:'doSomething1'
  }
  call_function(settings);
</script>
```

in your js file do things depending on the settings.mode value:

```
function call_function(settings)
{
    switch(settings.mode){
        case: 'doSomething1':
            //code for case1
            break;
        case: 'doSomething2':
            //code for case2
            break;
        default: 
            //code for default case
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That did not work. Where do I put this script tag? Where I want it invoked or at the end of the file?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Put the script tag at the end of the file before closing </body> tag

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your hosting plan:

If it's a dedicated or semi-dedicated server, I would prefer to have a shared JavaScript file (for performance).

If it is any other kind then separate file is faster as it distributes the load of requests in different JS files.

If you don't want to create separated files as it will be messy, I suggest to do the following:

```
<script src="somewhere">
var page = "<?PHP echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>";
Run_Function();
</script>
```

In somewhere:

```
function Run_function(){
switch(page){
case "1.php":
//Do Something
break;
case "2.php":
//Do Something else
break;
default:
alert("Unregistered webpage");
break;
}
```

Good Luck :D

EDIT:

Try up this function to get the file name from the URL:

```
function FileName(){
var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
return filename:
}
```

UPDATE:

Please check this improved function of the above:

```
function FileName(){
var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
if(filename == "" || filename == "Undefined"){
filename = "index.ruby";//or any other extension
}else{
var filename = filename.replace(/%C3%84/g, "Ä");
var filename = filename2.replace(/%C3%96/g, "Ö");
var filename = filename2.replace(/%C3%9C/g, "Ü");
var filename = filename2.replace(/%C3%A4/g, "ä");
var filename = filename2.replace(/%C3%B6/g, "ö");
var filename = filename2.replace(/%C3%BC/g, "ü");    
}
return filename:
}
```

This function might help more people and it is more flexible to use.

Comment: It's running on an EC2 instance within a VPC. It's a jQuery/HTML app that talks to a Rails back-end.

If it's a shared file, how can I call specific functions within that file?

As for your snippet, what is this `var page` doing? Please note that I am not using PHP and refraining from installing it on the server all-together. :)